# Kuhn's algorithm recursion elimination

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, bipartite

I'm trying to eliminate recursion in the following function (which is the part of Kuhn's algorithm implementation for bipartite graph maximum matching.):

```
static boolean findPath(List<Integer>[] graph, int u1,
                        int[] matching, boolean[] vis) {
vis[u1] = true;
  for (int v : graph[u1]) {
      int u2 = matching[v];
      if (u2 == -1 || !vis[u2] && findPath(graph, u2, matching, vis)) {
        matching[v] = u1;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
static boolean findPath(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph, int u1) {
    vis[u1] = true;

    Stack<Long> subgraphsToExplore = new Stack<Long>();
    List<Integer> subGraph = graph.get(u1);

    long container  = 0;

    for(Integer vertex : subGraph){
        container  = vertex;
        container <<= 17;
        container |= u1;
        subgraphsToExplore.push(container);
    }

    while(!subgraphsToExplore.empty()){

    container = subgraphsToExplore.pop();

    int v = (int)container >> 17;
    int u2 = matching[v];
    if (u2 == -1) { // v - is an exposed vertex in the path,
                    // the path is augmenting

        matching[v] = (int)(container & 0x1ffff); // first 17 bits others to zero
        return true;
      } 
      flag = false;
      if(!vis[u2]){ // v - is not an exposed vertex,
                    // but we haven't visited it on our dfs this time 
          List<Integer> subSubGraph = graph.get(u2);
          vis[u2] = true;

          long container1 = 0;

          for(int v1 : subSubGraph){
              if(!vis[v1]){
                  vis[v1] = true;
                  container1 = v1;
                  container1 <<= 17;
                  container1 |= u2;
                  subgraphsToExplore.push(container1);
              }
          }
      }     
  }

    return false;
  }
```

But I keep getting incorrect results. What am I missing here?
P.S.
[I took the recursive code from here](https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/kuhn_matching2)

Comment: These two methods can't be recursive-nonrecursive equivalents. There's much more going on in the second one.

Comment: Agreed with @laune. You show us two barely related codes and ask why they don't work the same. If that is the true question, please state it as such. If you indeed mean to translate the first code, please do the translation instead of just substituting it with other code, and ask the question related to the translation.

Answer (score 1):

When the first method finds a new path it will potentially update multiple positions in `matching` .

However, when the second method finds a new path it only updates a single position in `matching` and immediately returns.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, that's what I was missing. I also did realize, that if at some point in recursion calls chain findPath returns true, the all of the calls should return true up to the first one.